# How to save value in an array using python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I want to save a value into an array using numpy. All is working fine but when I try to save the values in the array I am getting an error. Here is what I've done so far:

```
import numpy as np
batchSize = 2
numClasses = 2
maxSeqLength = 10 #Maximum length of sentence

labels = []
arr = np.zeros([batchSize, maxSeqLength])

for i in range(batchSize):
    num = randint(1,17)
    labels.append([1,0])
    # print(num)
    print(labels)
    print(ids[num-1:num])
    arr[i]=ids[num-1:num]
```

When I print `ids` matrix I am getting these values

```
[[1, 0]]
[[   nan 11501.   420.  5842.    nan  4245.    nan     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]]
[[1, 0], [1, 0]]
[[   nan    nan  7624.  3936. 11501.  8064.  5842.    nan    nan  1087.
     37. 11516.    nan 10936.    nan 12111.     0.     0.     0.     0.
      0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]]
```

and this is the error I am getting when saving the `arr` array

```
could not broadcast input array from shape (30) into shape (10)
```

Comment: You define `numClasses` but don't ever use it. You use `maxSeqLength` but it is never defined.

Comment: He might have defined but, did not show it here. If he did not define it how is he printing those?

Comment: noofClasses is binary 1 0 represents positive classes

Comment: The error is pretty clear, you're trying to insert a array of 30 elements into an array of 10 elements. It means `arr[i]` has maxSeqLength while `ids[num-1:num]` has a different length.

Comment: @RockyLi Can you make an answer please.

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVohra as you wish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty clear, you're trying to insert a array of 30 elements into an array of 10 elements. It means `arr[i]` has `maxSeqLength=10` while `ids[num-1:num]` has a different `length=30`

You can fix this by setting `maxSeqLength=30` before you generate the `np.zero` matrix.

Comment: Should i exceed the max lenth to 30?

Comment: when i have set to maxlenth=30

i am getting 0  on every index of array

Comment: like this [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

Comment: values are not saving i guess